# Circularity symbol with datum?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, measurements, manufacturing-engineering, technical-drawing

I am trying to interpret a technical drawing that has a datum attached to a circularity GD&T symbol.

[This page](https://www.dimensionalconsulting.com/circularity.html) says that Circularity never has a datum reference. But this is a technical drawing from Apple that has been kept unchanged through 8 revisions, so don't want to be quick to say that it is a mistake.

My understanding is that the circularity is a set of 2 containing virtual circle that are perfectly circular and positioned in relation to the drawing geometry. The way I interpret this drawing is that the outer circle has a looser tolerance (+/-0.30mm r distance from centerpoint), and that the inner circle is then defined relative to that outer circle.

Am I interpreting this correctly? -- Is there a better way to do this? -- Would it still make sense to use these tolerances if the ring was fully closed?

[image: Drawing using Circularity with datum]

Drawing source: [Accessory Design Guidelines for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf) page 158 (R21)